# displaying same div on click side by side and limit it to screen width with latest click first

Tags: popup, chat, box

i am new in web development. i have data(username) appearing on website. Now, i want to make popups, chat boxes just like facebook. each username has different div id. I already have a div for chat box(msg_box). I need this div to show up side by side on each click at bottom of page . also latest clicked username appear first. thanks.

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nameid").click(function() {

    var text = $(this).text();

document.getElementById("bb").innerHTML=text;
});
});
</script>
    /head>
<body>

    <div class="container">


        <div class="header">
        </div>

        <div class="leftblock">     
        </div>

        <div class="chat_box" id="cb">
        <div class="chat_head_left"></div>
        <div class="chat_head_right"></div>
        <div class="chat_head">Members</div>
        <div class="chat_body">
        <?php
        for($i=1;$usernamee=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records); $i++)
        {



        echo  "<div class='nameid' id='$i'   <b>".$usernamee['username']."
        </br>"."</b></div>";

        }


        ?>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="msg_box"    style="right:290px">

            <div id="bb" class="msg_head">

                <div class="close">x</div>
            </div>
            <div class="msg_wrap">
                <div class="msg_body"></div>
                <div class="msg_footer" ><textarea class="msg_input" 
         rows="4">sample</textarea></div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about where you are stuck, and what you have tried to address it.

Comment: Thanks Antimony. I have list of members() drawn from database on the chat_box. I want to make chat boxes when i click them. I would like maximum of 5 chat boxes appear on the window, appending right to left with respect to members div(chat_box). I have given incremental id to these members.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time i entered wrong key.I try to be more organize n my thought here....... I have list of members(inside .chat_body) drawn from database .  I have given incremental id to these members.I want to make chat boxes when i click them. I would like maximum of 5 chat boxes appear on the window, appending right to left with respect to members div(chat_box).preferably replacing first chat box on 6th member click.I have class= msg_box , which i have styled. i want it to appear like appending chat boxes or inline blocks.i tried using append function.Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question to add these details!

Comment: Thanks I did it again